# Bash, excluding some file from the result of ls command, only by using the path

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I would like to exclude some files from the output of an ls command.

As an example, I have these files :

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# ls -drt1 test_dir/*.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN1-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN2-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN3-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN4-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN5-RANDOM.txt
```

I want to exclude files containing PATTERN2 and PATTERN3 (extended globbing is set)

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# ls -drt1 test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN1-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN4-RANDOM.txt
test_dir/FIXED-PATTERN5-RANDOM.txt
```

Works fine.

The problem is that I do not execute the ls command myself and I cannot modify the way it is launched : sh -c "ls -drt1 path".

I just have access to "path", passed as a parameter to an executable (binary) containing this sh -c command

When I give the executable the path "test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt", I have this error :

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `ls -drt1 test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt'
```

Which is exactly the same when doing this by myself in the console :

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# sh -c 'ls -drt1 test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `ls -drt1 test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt'
```

How can have the correct result via sh -c, by modifying only my expression :

```
test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: with `sh -c` you are using a different shell. Look to which shell it defaults and use the given syntax for that shell. Alternative you can use `grep` to exclude lines

Comment: Hmmm. It seems that it is bash, so it's the same I think
    [toto@damageinc ~]# readlink -e $(which sh)
    /bin/bash

Comment: Bash behaves differently if invoked as `sh`. Please invoke it as `bash` directly, and make sure to enable extglob on a separate line in the same shell instance.

Comment: I can't modify the invokation :( I only have access to the path given to the ls command

Comment: Presumably `extglob` is enabled in your `.bashrc` which isn't read if you are not running interactively. So you get the syntax error because `extglob`isn't enabled

Comment: If you have control over `path` as a string, you can make it a pipe to `grep`, eg like `test_dir | grep -Ev 'FIXED-(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-.*\.txt'`. Or if you really want an `extglob` dump the `ls` output to `/dev/null`, enable `extglob`, put a newline and then do a second `ls` with your pattern.

Comment: @Graeme : I would have first an error on the "!", not the parenthesis ?

Comment: @Julien, no, fairly sure the `!` has no special meaning in that context (no history expansion), so it could just be text. So the parser probably gets to the `(` before it realises something is wrong. The message does say 'near', so it is not claiming to know exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: @Graeme, you're right : sh -O extglob -c 'ls -drt1 test_dir/FIXED-!(PATTERN2|PATTERN3)-*.txt' is working. But I cannot use it, no control over sh options :( An for some reason, grep does not work as well, I'll look into that